# How to manage launchpad PPA in a team

Tags: ubuntu, packaging, launchpad

I recently set up a PPA for a software that I am developing together with the rest of the dev team. However I would like to give access to upload new packages and maintain them to whole dev team, not just me.

How do I do that on launchpad? Is it possible? I saw projects like https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-sdk-team/+archive/ppa which seems to be more like a team rather than individual.

Comment: Some explanation for downvotes would be nice :-)

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say it's because you don't seem to include any research (ie the "what have you tried" question). A google query gave me [this link](https://help.launchpad.net/Teams/CreatingAndRunning). Does this help at all in your situation?

Comment: Of course, I have been googling this for days, otherwise I wouldn't even bother asking, if it's so obvious, why these people don't add the link they found together with downvote?

Comment: I guess it's not their responsibility. I upvoted to keep you afloat, please add a description of what you've already tried to discourage further downvotes. It's a good question anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third line in the [PPA](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA) help page states that users and teams can have PPA. Therefore, if you want to have a PPA for a team, you need to first create a team, which you can do so on the Launchpad home page.